# Cordova not getting installed

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the ionic with the cordova . I had been using this since today evening and was trying with pushbots .
Now that I realise that I am not able to build the android project and I see that the cordova CLI is not installed now.

I wonder that got removed and I tried multiple times installing the ionic and cordova but all the times it shows that

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.2.0
Xcode version: Xcode 6.1.1 Build version 6A2008a 


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly suggested to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`
 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications. `npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices. `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************
```

I am not sure what is happening . I tried many a times installing the cordova but it is not coming up.
what to be done . please help me

Comment: did you do `npm install -g ionic sim` ?